# matlab, histogram how to find my data in the plot

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have my data in 2 vectors. 
Then using [n,xout] = hist(x,y) returns vectors n and xout containing the frequency counts and the bin locations. 
x are my real data and y the segment where I want to build my histogram.
Than I use bar(xout,n) to plot the histogram. In the end I am fitting this histogram with gaussian fit.

Now I would like to know where my real data (each point of vector x), are located in the histogram?
Can someone help me to figure out them?

Answer (score 1):

```
[~, result] =  min(abs(bsxfun(@minus, y(:), x(:).')));
```

This gives, for each value in `x`, the index of the closest element in `y`. So `y(result)` is the closest element in `y` for each `x`.

Example:

```
>> x = [0.4 1.6 5.3 4.2 3.1 7.8];
>> y = [0 2 4 6 8];
>> [~, result] =  min(abs(bsxfun(@minus, y(:), x(:).')))
result =
     1     2     4     3     3     5
>> y(result)
ans =
     0     2     6     4     4     8
```

Comment: But how can I find the location of each point of x in histogram?

Comment: I would like that after doing the histogram to find where is x=0.4 or x=1.6

Comment: @user3714919 Well, that's what my answer provides, isn't it? For `x(1)` equal to 0.4, `result(1)` is `1`, telling you `x(1)` it's in the first interval; or `y(result(1))` is `0`, telling you the center of that interval

Comment: Ok, i understood now. But when I am doing for my results it gives me that all my points are in interval 21, 23, while i have almost everywhere in my histogram, and this is that make me confused. Does it make any problem that my y = [-4:0.2:2]

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `histc`.

```
[binCounts, idx] = histc(x, y);
```

Then to find the bin in which a certain value of x is:

```
bin = idx(x == 0.4);
```

Just watch out since `histc` second input is not the centers like `hist`, but the end value of each bin. So you might need to change your `y` vector.